# Unclear parenthesis instruction "this.fn.bind(this)(super.fn(...args)"

Tags: javascript, typescript

So in a project, I've found code which can be stripped down to:

```js
export abstract class Logger {
    private static log(level: LogLevels, ...args: Array<any>) {/**/}
    public error(...args: Array<any>): LogData {
        return Logger.log(LogLevels.ERROR, ...args);
    }
}

export class LoggerService extends Logger {
    public error(...args: Array<any>): any {
        return this._log.bind(this)(super.error(...args));
    }

    private _log(logData: LogData) {
        let logstashLoggerData = this.extendLoggerData(logData);
        return this.logStashApi.log(logstashLoggerData)
            .toPromise()
            .catch(err => console.error(err));
    }

}
```

And I'm a bit concerned by the line with `this._log.bind(this)(super.error(...args));`.

I see something like this for the first time, so I prefer to be cautious and not break anything. It's not anything Promise or `.bind()` specific, is it? From my tests, it appears that the statement can be plainly simplified to `this._log(super.error(...args));` (but then why to complicate?), can someone confirm?

Comment: "*It appears that the statement can be plainly simplified to `this._log(super.error(...args));`*" - yes. There's no reason to overcomplicate this. An intermediate step would be `this._log.call(this, super.error(...args))`.

Comment: It might come from someone having "inlined" `this._log = this._log.bind(this)`, which is usually to be found in constructors to bind methods and allow their use as callbacks.

Comment: It's rather intentional because there are 4 methods (error, warn, info, debug) written in the same way, it's just added more to my confusion. Thanks for confirming that I can throw this ballast away :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can and *should* get rid of this inline binding. I would recommend moving it into the constructor of the class though (instead of just getting rid of binding altogether) because then you could use the service methods (`error`, `warning` etc.) as "plain functions", which would be helpful if you need to export them from your module without exposing the LoggerService instance itself